# Looking for an event that fires when a property's get is called

Tags: c#, winforms, propertygrid

I'm using PropertyGrid in my application. I needed to change the visibility and readonly for some properties at run-time up on custom *data* criteria.

Although I didn't find something easy & ready for it, I found a workaround by changing the `ReadOnlyAttribute` and `BrowsableAttribute`  properties at runtime as the following:

```
protected void SetBrowsable(string propertyName, bool value)
{
    PropertyDescriptor property = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(GetType())[propertyName];
    BrowsableAttribute att = (BrowsableAttribute)property.Attributes[typeof(BrowsableAttribute)];
    FieldInfo cat = att.GetType().GetField("browsable", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

    if (property.Attributes.Cast<Attribute>().Any(p => p.GetType() == typeof(BrowsableAttribute)))
        cat.SetValue(att, value);
}

protected void SetReadOnly(string propertyName, bool value)
{
    PropertyDescriptor property = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(GetType())[propertyName];
    ReadOnlyAttribute att = (ReadOnlyAttribute)property.Attributes[typeof(ReadOnlyAttribute)];
    FieldInfo cat = att.GetType().GetField("isReadOnly", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

    if (property.Attributes.Cast<Attribute>().Any(p => p.GetType() == typeof(ReadOnlyAttribute)))
        cat.SetValue(att, value);
}
```

Now, my problem is that where I should call these methods? is there any event that I can handle for an `object` to call these methods? Maybe by implementing an interface.

Answer (score 1):

There is no inbuilt event that fires when a property-get is called, unless you write one.

Of course, if you write a custom descriptor (PropertyDescriptor, typically chained to the reflection descriptor as a decorator) you can intercept access **via the descriptor only** (data binding, etc), and do whatever you want - but for arbitrary types (including those you didn't write).

Setting attribute values via reflection at runtime is... not great. This is working largely by accident of TypeDescriptor caching. If you are going to do that, TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes (or similar) is preferable. However, what you are trying to do is done much more appropriately by implementing a custom model. Depending on where you are displaying this, this can be done by one or:

- adding a custom TypeConverter, overriding GetProperties, and provide custom descriptors at runtime based on the data - works primarily for PropertyGrid
- implementing ICustomTypeDescriptor in your object, implementing GetProperties, and provide custom descriptors at runtime based on the data - works for most controls
- adding a custom TypeDescriptionProvider and associate with the type (TypeDescriptor.AddProvider), providing an ICustomTypeDescriptor that behaves like above; this separates the object from the descriptor voodoo

Al of these are tricky! The easiest is the TypeConverter option, which works well because you mention PropertGrid. Inherit from ExpandableObjectConverter, and override GetProperties, filtering as needed, and supplying a custom descriptor for the read-only one as needed. Then attach a TypeConverterAttribute to your type, specifying your custom converter type.

Emphasis: this branch of .NET is pretty complex, obscure, and in diminishing usage. But it works.